# I'm in trouble with getting the response for a HTTP POST Request

Tags: c#, post

I'm trying to get a http response from a web server which asks for my credentials in `application/json`. Although on their website they say I have to use POST Request, I get 405 HTTP status and a `WebException` as an answer. Here is my code:

```
private bool RunAuth(bool b, String user, String pass)
{
    if(b)
    {
        HttpWebRequest h = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/");
        h.Method = "POST";
        h.KeepAlive = false;

        h.ContentType = "application/json";
        String json = "{" + "\"agent\": {" + "\"name\": \"Minecraft\"," + "\"version\": 1" + "}," + "\"username\": \""+user+"\"," + "\"password\": \""+pass+"\"," + "\"clientToken\": \"" + tokenGenerated + "\"" + "}"; //tokenGenerated = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        h.ContentLength = json.Length;

        using(var stream = new StreamWriter(h.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            stream.Write(json);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)h.GetResponse();
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            String result = stream.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(appdata + @"\.craftunio\authtest.txt", result);
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is caused by a design failure that was resolved in a manner that is unhelpful for future readers, and that the problem itself would had been resolved par user's own inspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong endpoint.  You should call

```
HttpWebRequest h = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add it :)